# Java Replace Regex - replace consecutive tabs

Tags: java, regex, replace

```
"aaaa    bbbb        dddd        ffff        ".replace("\\t\\t", "\\tx\\t");
```

I want to **insert an 'x'** in between **two consecutive tabs**.
I think i got the Java Regex pattern wrong. **Could someone tell me whats wrong?**
The output should be:

```
"aaaa    bbbb    x    dddd    x    ffff    x    "
```

Comment: The `replace` method doesn't work with regexes. Also, you don't need to escape an escape character. Try `.replace("\t\t", "\tx\t")`

Comment: It worked! Post your answer.

Comment: Someone already did it, accept @user3218114's answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s = s.replaceAll("\t(?=\t)", "\tx");
```

It needs a regular expression (replaceAll/replaceFirst) which `replace`  is not, because for three tabs it would already have skipped two tabs, hence no two 'x's.

The above is a look-ahead.

Two backslashes are used for regex escaping, to represent a backslash itself. The single backslash escapes in String literals, and `\u0061` (small letter 'a') can be placed everywhere like in `public cl`\u0061`ss C`.

Answer (score 3):

The sample string doesn't contains any tab character. They are just spaces. In Java tab is represented by `\t` in the string.

```
System.out.println("aaaa\tbbbb\t\tdddd\t\tffff\t\t".replace("\t\t", "\tx\t"));
```

output:

```
aaaa    bbbb    x   dddd    x   ffff    x
```

---

Normally a tab contains  four spaces. You can check for spaces.